# Does HttpPost only returns xml and not json?

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-json

I've been working on a project that sends data to the server and receives a return value of `JSON` data. Unfortunately when I try to use `HttpPost` it returns as `xml` and not `JSON`.

I was able to fix the problem by using `HttpGet`.

I am just curious if it is possible to return `JSON` data using `HttpPost`? Can anyone enlightened me? I've been Googling around for a while but still unable to find any answers to my question.

P.S.
Please don't flag my question.

Comment: that have nothing to do with Android or any other client-side software. That's configured/programmed in the server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: which type of output you are getting???

Comment: Something like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: yes I can. There's a line of code in the server that says: `if(POST) sendXml(); else sendSomethingElse();` It's not the client (Android) code. It's the server code.

Comment: I see. You can post your answer so I can mark it as correct since you were the first one to comment. Although zozelfelfo answered first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your `HttpPost` or `HttpGet`, the key point here is your server. When it receives a POST it is programmed to return a XML-like string and if it gets a GET it will return a JSON-like string

Answer (score 1):

If it is a third-party server, make sure you set the corresponding parameters for the format you would like to retrieve. Typically this is the [Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). If it is your own server, zozelfelfo is right and it depends on your implementation, but not on the HTTP verb.